# Reasons why matrix definition is not element by element?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone give me some examples of the inconveniences that would occur if you defined the regular matrix product as element wise (aka Hadamard product)?

I've been told the reason why it's defined this way is simply because it's useful, but I'd like some concrete examples which couldn't be fixed by simply reordering elements around in the matrix to accommodate the new definition.

Comment: The point of matrix-matrix multiplication being defined the way it is is so that $(AB)x=A(Bx)$ if $A$ is $m \times n$, $B$ is $n \times p$, and $x$ is $p \times 1$. That is, matrix-matrix multiplication corresponds to function composition of matrix-vector multiplication. The Hadamard product has its uses but it's nowhere near as useful as this.

Comment: @Ian In our hypothetical scenario that we redefine matrix multiplication, then a vector itself would be a linear transformation.

Comment: That's a rather backwards way of doing things, though, isn't it? We generally want to think of matrices transforming vectors into other vectors, not vectors transforming matrices into vectors.

Comment: @Ian But that would fit the scalar analogy world where a plain old number is a linear transformation on a plain old number: 4 *4

Comment: @Ian Well, no, I did not consider a matrix when addressing how to linearly transform a vector

Comment: There is no suitable scalar analogy because scalars don't have such domain restrictions. More to the point, with your "vectors linearly transform matrices into vectors" system, as far as I can tell there's no function composition at all, which is a serious defect of a system of transformations.

Comment: In short: Because it would be incredibly uninteresting otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

In mathematics generally, it’s not definitions that come first, but phenomena.

And in this case, we have the problem of describing the composition of two linear transformations. Start with $f:U\to V$ and $g:V\to W$, whose composition $g\circ f$ needs a description. We can describe $f$ and $g$ by matrices of appropriate shape, and similarly $g\circ f$ by a matrix. Lo and behold! the matrix of the last is the product of the first two.